# MVC 3 Membership service resetpassword Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

I currently have an MVC 3 application which requires the Security Answer to be correct when user forgets the password.

However, I want a System Administrator to be able to Reset the Password of any user without knowing the Security Answer.

Any possible solution for this?

Comment: Can you show the code that you currently have?  What do you have setup in regards to an Administrator page?  More details would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using two different Providers for this solution.
Both providers were added to the Web.Config file of the application:

```
<membership>
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="ProviderRequiredAnswer"  .......
       enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" ...... />
    <add name="ProviderNoRequiredAnswer"  ......
       enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" ...... />

   </providers>
</membership>
```

When regular user forgets password and needs to reset it, I will get user using the first provider by:

MembershipUser user = 
     Membership.Providers["**ProviderRequiredAnswer**"].GetUser(model.userToReset, false);

**string autoGenPass = userToReset.ResetPassword(model.PasswordAnswer);**

bool resetPasswordSucceeded = userToReset.ChangePassword(autoGenPass, model.NewPassword);

On the other hand, if a System Admin, who does not have the Security Answer needs to Reset the password of an user, I will get user using the second provider by:

MembershipUser user = 
     Membership.Providers["**ProviderNoRequiredAnswer**"].GetUser(model.userToReset, false);

**string autoGenPass = userToReset.ResetPassword();**

bool resetPasswordSucceeded = userToReset.ChangePassword(autoGenPass, model.NewPassword);

Comment: That's an interesting solution.  I didn't even know you could use multiple providers like that.